# azur Text to speech SDK and Text to speech REST API offline use

Tags: android, azure, kotlin, text-to-speech

Is there option to automatically download voices in azur Text to speech SDK and Text to speech REST API, in their cognitive-sample-sdk kotin sample code there is option to set voice

```
speechConfig?.speechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-IN-NeerjaNeural"
```

we can set any voice a user wants by getting voice lists with and set newly selected voice

```
tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/voices/list
```

But my question is getting the voice list/setting one voice from the list and reading text aloud is taking place online and how can we possibly download the voices first and read aloud the text afterwards. so this way i have the option to use the text to speech functionality even when the device is offline once the voice is downloaded in the device.

I haven't found ways to accomplish this in the azur TTS documentation or sample code repository, any help on this is much appriciated.

> **Quickstart: Convert text to speech**
> [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=macos%2Cterminal&pivots=programming-language-java#next-steps](https://stackoverflow.com)

> **Text to speech REST API**
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech?tabs=streaming

> **Speech synthesis sample for Android(kotlin example)**
> [https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/kotlin/android/tts-pause-example](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Azure Text to Speech service does not offer a built-in feature to automatically download voices for offline use. The speech synthesis voices provided by Azure Text to Speech are generated and hosted on Microsoft's servers. The service is primarily designed for online use, where text is sent to the API, and the generated speech audio is returned in real time.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, yeah you know this is a very bad experience for users with low network, it's was good if there was a pre-download option to make it smooth..